# Error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int. Problem with code for a java course i'm doing

Tags: java

I have this task for my Java course but keep getting this error and don't know where i've gone wrong.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[] values = new double[4];
        
        for (double i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            values[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    
        double sum = (values[0] + values[1] + values[2] + values[3]);
        
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum + ".");

        sc.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (double i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {` why should `i` be a `double`? This causes problems when you later use it as an index to an array, which converts it to an `int` and causes the error.

Comment: Also, via `sc.nextInt()` you will never read a `double`, only an `int`. So why not use [`nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--)?

Comment: When i tried it as an int, I got errors when inputting numbers with decimals.

Comment: Also, you don't need the array itself to find the sum. You could just do `sum+=sc.nextDouble()`

Comment: @WogChamp what is this "it" that you tried as an int?

Comment: Here's the error I get when I use ```for (int i = 0;``` :
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
at ArraySum.main(ArraySum.java:12)

Comment: @WogChamp it's not possible you're getting that error only by declaring `i` as an `int`. That's because you're using `nextInt` instead of `nextDouble`

Comment: That stacktrace clearly shows you usinhg `nextInt()` when it occurs.  Use `nextDouble` to read a double value from the `Scanner`.  Note - you have two bugs - 1. using double for `i` rather than int, 2. reading an int rather than a double.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (double i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
```

Why should `i` be a `double` here?

This causes problems when you later use `i` as an index to an array, which converts it to an `int` and causes the error.

Just make `i` an `int`

```
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
```

About the exception you mention in the comments

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException 
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258) 
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212) 
    at ArraySum.main(ArraySum.java:12)
```

that's because you're using `nextInt` instead of `nextDouble`, so when you enter a value with a decimal separator, `Scanner` throws an error because it can't interpret the input as an integer.

Here's the full working code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[] values = new double[4];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            values[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        }
    
        double sum = (values[0] + values[1] + values[2] + values[3]);
        
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum + ".");

        sc.close(); 
    }
}
```